# Swift method insertSubview at index works well. But how to reposition all subviews to make room for inserted one

Tags: ios, swift

I have added 4 subviews(label1, label2, label3, label4) and constraints(label2 top depends on label1 bottom and so on) programatically to a particular view. Now I insert another subview at index 1(label5) using insertSubiewAtIndex method. Now how to refresh the UI as constraints are dynamic means label5 should take label1 position and label1 should take label2 position and so on.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label1 = UILabel()
    label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label1.text = "label1"
    label1.numberOfLines = 0
    label1.tag = 1

    self.containerView.addSubview(label1)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true


    let label2 = UILabel()
    label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label2.text = "label2"
    label2.numberOfLines = 0
    label2.tag = 1

    self.containerView.addSubview(label2)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label2, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView.subviews[self.containerView.subviews.count - 2], attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label2, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label2, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true


    let label3 = UILabel()
    label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label3.text = "label3"
    label3.numberOfLines = 0
    label3.tag = 1

    self.containerView.addSubview(label3)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label3, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView.subviews[self.containerView.subviews.count - 2], attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label3, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label3, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true


    let label4 = UILabel()
    label4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label4.text = "label4"
    label4.numberOfLines = 0
    label4.tag = 1

    self.containerView.addSubview(label4)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label4, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView.subviews[self.containerView.subviews.count - 2], attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label4, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label4, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    let label5 = UILabel()
    label5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label5.text = "label5"
    label5.numberOfLines = 0
    label5.tag = 1

    self.containerView.addSubview(label5)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label5, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView.subviews[0], attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label5, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: label5, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label1.text = "label1"
        label1.numberOfLines = 0
        label1.tag = 1

        self.containerView.addSubview(label1)

        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label2.text = "label2"
        label2.numberOfLines = 0
        label2.tag = 1

        self.containerView.addSubview(label2)

        let label3 = UILabel()
        label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label3.text = "label3"
        label3.numberOfLines = 0
        label3.tag = 1

        self.containerView.addSubview(label3)

        let label4 = UILabel()
        label4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label4.text = "label4"
        label4.numberOfLines = 0
        label4.tag = 1

        self.containerView.addSubview(label4)

        let label5 = UILabel()
        label5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label5.text = "label5"
        label5.numberOfLines = 0
        label5.tag = 1

        self.containerView.addSubview(label5)

        setConstraint(to: [label5, label1, label2, label3, label4])
    }

    private func setConstraint(to views: [UIView]) {
        var iterator  = views.makeIterator()
        var prev: UIView = self.containerView
        while let next = iterator.next() {
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: prev, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 16).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

            NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
            prev = next
        }
    }
```

Comment: What i actually want to achieve is - i want to insert a view at particular index of parent view on any event. Parent view is already loaded and have many views with constraints. Lets say the event is switch inside the same parent view. On switch clicked on i want to insert a view at index after switch, on switch off added view should be removed. My problem is all constraints are already there and there are many views of different types. All constraints are dynamic like self.containerView.subviews[self.containerView.subviews.count - 2]. Should i have to remove constraints and add them again?

Comment: Yes. contentView.removeConstraints(contentView.constraints) then add new constraints.